# How to get temp Static IP

Tags: ip, remote-debugging

I am configuring remote debugger and I am thinking to have static ip for my machine with the IDE, so the server can forward requests to my local machine behind WiFi in local LAN. I believe there is way i can obtain static IP like temporary one for my machine without going to ISA Provider, is there? What is the service? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

http://www.noip.com was the answer I was looking for

Comment: the website does not open.